# Share WordPress Database

Tags: database, customization

Does the WordPress installation has to use an exclusive database? I'm building a website with custom pages, that access a MySQL database. But the site will also have a WordPress installation. Can I use the same database unique for WordPress and the custom pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the WordPress installation has to use an exclusive database?

If there are no table name conflicts, WordPress can share a database. Preventing conflicts is just a matter of setting a database prefix on install. By default, that prefix is `wp_` but you can change it to anything you want within reasonable character limits. It should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Any custom site can be built within a WordPress installation, as it's back-end is completely coded with PHP, and MySQL. But [for many reasons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56121/can-i-use-php-sql-functions-instead-of-wpdb) you are not recommended to use MySQL queries in WordPress, but to use [`$wpdb` class refrerence](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). And you can make as many as pages you need by using WordPress [custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

You can create a page template by simply putting the following codes into a new `.php` file:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

Then you can create a new page in WordPress admin panel and can choose the template easily. And [this Q & A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90392/how-to-display-page-content-in-a-page-template) will also help you achieve something you may want.

Even you can make new tables within your WordPress db, and can add/edit/delete/query certain things from the new custom tables. But for always, using `$wpdb` is recommended [for many reasons](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56121/can-i-use-php-sql-functions-instead-of-wpdb)<sup>(you know now)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. I'm not building the custom part as custom WP pages, but now after this answer I'll be considering doing it, since I didn't know much about these capabilities. Thanks a lot for clarifying.